# When user submit form groupid append as button when clicked on groupId form will be edited how can do? I

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After form submission group-id should append bellow as button with gId value. When user clicks on that button, the form should be edited.

How can i do this? I tried with the following code

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="groupId" ng-model="user.gId" />
  <input type="text" name="groupName" ng-model="user.gname" />
  <input type="button" value="button" id="submit" ng-click="userInfo(user.gid);" />
</form>

<p>submitedGruopus clikon form Edit {{appedGroupIdAsButton}}</p>


<script>
  $scope.submitedGroup= []
  $scope.userInfo = function(data){
    $scope.submited.push($compile("<button ng-click=openPopup("+data+");>"+data+"</button>")($scope););
  }
  $scope.appedGroupIdAsButton = $scope.submitedGroup;
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add `groupId` to the model? Where the `groupId` should come from?

Comment: yes your right, how can do that ?

Comment: Again,  Where the groupId should come from? describe the steps of what the user should do and what he should see..

Comment: when user submited form . user object will generates . user object contains keys like gId, gName. gId. when function calls gIds appended here{{appedGroupIdAsButton}}

Comment: I added code in jsfiddle can you help me now http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10124/

Comment: where the `$scope.submited` come from. I fill that I don't sucssed to understand the scenario, sorry.